# OPENGL: How can I move alpha to red channel using blit

Tags: opengl, graphics, alpha, framebuffer, blit

I'm trying to debug my gbuffer framebuffer. I managed to blit the RGB components with ease, but I want to remap the alpha to red or rgb for greyscale, so that I can debug the alpha component as well without blending. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just read the alpha?

Comment: @Nicol My question is regarding moving the alpha to a different channel. If you have values for RGB then using an alpha channel as well will make it indecipherable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to display a single color channel as is, then `glColorMask` should be enough.

Say you only want to display the red channel, you could do:

```
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
```

If you want to switch 2 color channels or apply a grayscale effect, then running it all through a shader is probably the easiest way:

```
uniform sampler2D frame;

in vec2 uv;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture(frame, uv);

    // Grayscale
    color.rgb = vec3((color.r + color.g + color.b) * 0.33);

    // Switch red and alpha channels
    color.ra = color.ar;

    fragColor = color;
}
```

So instread of blitting the framebuffer, you draw a fullscreen quad with the framebuffer as the bound texture.

Comment: Thanks, Vallentin! There's no other way to swap channels, though? I'd like to minimize overhead if possible, and I feel like using a command would be better.

Comment: @KarimAbdelHamid As far as I recall, there isn't. Also blitting can be both faster but also slower than drawing a fullscreen quad. So normally you're better of just doing that. Bottom line is though to always benchmark if it becomes and actual performance problem.

Comment: Decided to go with the quad route. Thanks!